# Drag NSView by discrete distances like in mac calendar standart app

Tags: objective-c, macos, draggable, nsview

Can somebody tell me how to implement the dragging of the view, as it is implemented in the standart mac calendar app, when we drad event view in calendar grid, it moved by discrete distances.
 I try to make it throught override -(void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event in my custom view class.

Comment: And more if you need them: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+snap+to+grid ("snap to grid" is a common term for this feature).

Comment: Thank you very much, just do not know how to properly named this feature)